# BackboneJS - same el for many views

Tags: backbone.js

I am using same `el` for more than 1 view like below. I'm not facing any problem till now. Is this good approach or should i do any changes?

```
<div id="app">
     <div id="app-header"></div>
     <div id="app-container"></div>
     <div id="app-footer">
</div>
```

**App View:**

```
{
el: "#app",

v1: new View1(),
v2: new View2(),
render: function () {     
   if (cond1) {    
       this.v1.render();
   } else if (cond2) {    
       this.v2.render();
   }}
}
```

**View 1:**

```
{
  el: "#app-container",

  render: function (){
    this.$el.html(template);
  }
}
```

**View 2:**

```
{
  el: "#app-container",

  render: function (){
    this.$el.html(template);
  }
}
```

Comment: All your DOM events defined in your views will be bind to that element, if you are fine with that then it's probably OK. Another thing is all other views' HTML will be gone if you ever call `remove` or `this.$el.html(...)` on one of the views.

Comment: it's not a good approach, I would say, add 4 (as many as you want) child div inside and that use one for each view. as @j03w said, this will lead to problem in future

Comment: good points. And i am not appending my dom directly into el. I append dom into other divs, in all views. So i don't use `this.$el.html(...)`

Comment: @j03w @ Ravi, i updated my question.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#View-el

Comment: ya. i read that lot of times. :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not have view1's `el` as `#v1` and so on? That way each view is self-contained and your events will be properly localized rather than having several views binding their events to the same `el`.

Comment: @muistooshort see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TFtLL/1/. what is wrong in having same el for all views?

Comment: Events are the usual source of problems. I still don't know why you want to do it this way, it gains you nothing but brittleness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading your question, I do not really see what advantages you could possibly have using this approach rather than having the different `div` elements being the root `el` for your views 1, 2, 3 and using

```
this.$el.html(template)
```

in the `render` method.

Your approach could work for a small application, but I think it will become really hard to maintain as the application grows.

EDIT

I still do not really get your point, you could only initialize everything only once in both cases.

Here is a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFtLL/).
By the way I am changing the content by listening to the click event but this is to simplify the example. It should be done by the router.

Comment: updated my question again. i need to call `View 1` render many times. By my method, i can avoid more initialization, because i initialized v2, 3, 4 as v1's property.

Comment: My situation is exactly similar to this. http://jsfiddle.net/TFtLL/1/. what is wrong in having `#container` as `el` in v1, v2 and v3. How could it become unmanageable in large apps.

Comment: What you are doing in your example, and I think is adding complexity, is having different containers (`#v2`, `#v3` and so on) where all the subviews should really have `#container` or whatever you want them to be contained into as their root element.

Comment: Sorry, after reading my last comment I realized that is not exactly what I was trying to say.
The subview should be **contained** (as shown in my Fiddle) by the same `div` or whatever, but not have it as their root element. Otherwise the events of an inactive subview could trigger unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

I do use a mixin to handle such situation, I call it stated view. For a view with all other options I will send a parameter called 'state', render will in-turn call renderState first time and there after every time I set a 'state' renderState will update the view state. Here is my mixin code looks like.

```
var setupStateEvents = function (context) {

    var stateConfigs = context.getOption('states');
    if (!stateConfigs) {
        return;
    }

    var state;
    var statedView;


    var cleanUpState = function () {
        if (statedView) {
            statedView.remove();
        }
    };

    var renderState = function (StateView) {
        statedView = util.createView({
            View: StateView,
            model: context.model,
            parentEl: context.$('.state-view'),
            parentView:context
        });
    };

    context.setState = function (toState) {
        if (typeof toState === 'string') {
            if (state === toState) {
                return;
            }
            state = toState;
            var StateView = stateConfigs[toState];
            if (StateView) {
                cleanUpState();
                renderState(StateView);
            } else {
                throw new Error('Invalid State');
            }

        } else {
            throw new Error('state should be a string');
        }
    };

    context.getState = function () {
        return state;
    };

    context.removeReferences(function(){
        stateConfigs = null;
        state=null;
        statedView=null;
        context=null;
    })

};
```

full code can be seen here

https://github.com/ravihamsa/baseapp/blob/master/js/base/view.js

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Backbone Rule:**

> When you create an instance of a view, it'll bind all events to el if
> it was assigned, else view creates and assigns an empty div as el for that view and bind
> all events to that view.

In my case, if i assign `#app-container` to view 1 and view 2 as `el` and when i initialize both views like below in `App View`, all events bind to the same container (i.e #app-container)

```
this.v1 = new App.View1();
this.v2 = new App.View2();
```

**Will it lead to any memory leaks / Zombies?**

No way. No way. Because ultimately you are having only one instance for each view. So this won't cause any memory leaks.

**Where does it become problematic?**

When your app grows, it is very common to use same id for a tag in both views. For example, you may have `button` with an id `btn-save` in both view's template. So when you bind btn-save in both views and when you click button in any one the view, it will trigger both views save method.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TFtLL/7/). This'll explain this case.

**Can i use same `el` for both view?**

It is up to you. If you avoid binding events based on same id or class name in both views, you won't have any problem. But you can avoid using same id but it's so complex to avoid same class names in both views.

So for me, it looks @Daniel Perez answer is more promising. So i'm going to use his approach.